# Android Studio Camera api 2 How to take a picture and save to phone?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

I load the camera in a surface Texture and i want to take a picture by clicking a button. How do i do that?

I want when the app opens and the camera opens as well the user can click on a button and take a picture. that picture should be saved into the phone storage.

This is my code:

```
    public class zambelislightscamapp extends Activity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;
    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            setupCamera(width, height);
            connectCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice; private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {


        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            mCameraDevice = camera;
            startPreview();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            //         "Camera connection made!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    };



    private HandlerThread mBackgroundHandlerThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private String mCameraId;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private Size mVideoSize;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private int mTotalRotation;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;

    private ImageButton mRecordImageButton;
    //silvia button #1
    private ImageButton clickButtonPlusImg;
    private ImageButton clickButtonMinusImg;
    private Button backButton;
    private boolean mIsRecording = false;

    private File mVideoFolder;
    private String mVideoFileName;

    private Button btnCapture = null;

    private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
    }

    private static class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {


            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() /
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }
    }
    int windowwidth;
    int windowheight;

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera2_video_image);

//START
        windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

        img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) img
                        .getLayoutParams();
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                        if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                            x_cord = windowwidth;
                        }
                        if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                            y_cord = windowheight;
                        }

                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 1;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 1;

                        img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```